# Bootstrap popovers with Fullcalendar - double click to show?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Having a weird problem with a Bootstrap popover attached to a Fullcalendar event click.

First click does nothing, subsequent clicks toggle the popover just fine.

My guess is the first click is initiating the popover but not showing it, but that's just a guess. The code fragment I'm using within Fullcalendar to create the popover is this:

```
            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                $this = $(this);
                $this.popover({
                    html:true,
                    title:event.title,
                    content:event.content,
                    trigger:'click',
                    placement:'top',
                    container:'body'
                }).popover();
                return false;            
            },
```

Any wise owls spot what I'm doing wrong? Way to much code to do a fiddle on this one, so hoping someone recognises the problem and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is:
First Click: you create the popover on the event object ($(this)), and tell it to trigger on 'click'.

So then you have to click again to have it trigger.

Try changing `trigger: 'hover'`, or create the popover for each even in the
`eventRender:` call of fullcalendar.

Comment: Brilliant. Moved the creation of the popover to eventRender (changed the trigger to 'focus') and added $this.popover('toggle'); to the eventClick and it works like a charm. Thanks for your help!